# DIV moving up and down using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good day,
I'm building a website where I would like to have a div moving down and back up on a click(clicking on another div area).
It regards the header of a page with an account image inside (the header contains from left to right: logo, horizontal menu, shopping cart and account symbol)

when I click the account symbol I want the header to slide down (60 pixels) and I want another div (with account related links in it) to show up above  the header that just slid down.
I've achieved something but I'm really not happy with it:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $(".account").click(function);
            $("#accountbar").slideToggle( "slow");
            $("#topheader").toggleClass("topheader topheaderdown");
            $("#contentarea").toggleClass("content contentdown");
        });
    });
</script>
```

1) So what this does it loads the new account bar (height 60px) and slides this one down.

2) It displays the topheader down another 60px (css style rule top: 60px)

3) It also displays the rest of the content (the main content) down 120 pixels lower than normal when both the account bar and topheader are being displayed (by default this value is 60px, so only for the topheader)

I want things to "smoothly" slide down and back up when clicking on the account image. I got this far (for the smoothly moving down the topheader part):

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $("#account").on('click',function(){
            $("#accountinner").toggle(function() {
                $("#topheaderid").animate({ top: '-=60px' }, 500);
            },function() {
                $("#topheaderid").animate({ top: '+=60px' }, 500);
            })
        });
    });
</script>
```

PROBLEM 1: the above is only moving the topheader down further and further every time I click on it (not going back up 60px again as specified)...

PROBLEM 2: The above is also somehow sliding my account image to the right (out of screen)

And I would like to implement the other rules in this too, so that on a click the topheader just moves down smoothly with 60px, up the top appears the account navigation in a new div (accountbar) AND the content (class content) moves down another 60px. As said before using "slidetoggle" and "toggleclass" works but I much rather have the "animate" function do the job as this looks awesome.
I have implemented these rules from the first script but it does not happen "smoothly" obviously and the topheader just keeps on going down...

I hope this is enough info and someone can help :)
When this works I want to extend this with a search button as well that appears below the topheader on click.

https://jsfiddle.net/d14tcb9n

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply perumal but no i was exactly after what madalin solved below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger the animations like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $("#account").on('click',function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('open')) {
         $("#topheaderid").animate({ top: '0' }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
        $("#accountbar").animate({ height: '0' }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
        $('#contentid').animate({ marginTop: '60px' }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
        $(this).removeClass('open');   
  } else {
        $("#topheaderid").animate({ top: '60px' }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
        $("#accountbar").animate({ height: '60px' }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
        $('#contentid').animate({ marginTop: '120px' }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
        $(this).addClass('open');  
  }


  });
});
```

remove the display none from the hidden div and change the height to 0
demo:https://jsfiddle.net/o1cvho6m/

Comment: Thank you very much madalin! This is exactly what i was looking for!! I'll implement it tomorrow and try to add the search bar below as well. Cheers

Comment: Resetting values onclick: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46124655/javascript-jquery-reset-values-onclick