# Javascript Jquery reset values onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've been working on this website header with divs moving up and down on a click, so clicking on the search button brings up a searchbar and clicking on the account button brings up an accountbar. With some great help from Madalin I've achieved this (article "[DIV moving up and down using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087899/div-moving-up-and-down-using-javascript)").

However... Is there a way to reset the javascript on clicking of either one of the buttons (so either "search" or "account"). I need this because now when you click once it works but when for example search has been clicked already and you click account you have to click twice again on search to see action... Please refer to the jsfiddle: [https://jsfiddle.net/27jaodcg][1]

So when you click account it closes the searchbar and when you click the search bar it closes the accountbar, this works perfect (once).

But when account has been clicked before the script "thinks" accountbar is still open so when clicking search it closes the accountbar but when clicking on account again nothing happens as the script closes accountbar first (but its closed already by the search button click).

I hope this makes sense :)

Below is the Javascript Jquery code so far:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $("#account").on('click',function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('open')) {
        $("#topheaderid").animate({ top: '0' }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
        $("#accountbarid").animate({ height: '0' }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
        $("#searchbarid").animate({ height: '0' }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
        $('#contentid').animate({ marginTop: '60px' }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
        $(this).removeClass('open');   
  } else {
        $("#topheaderid").animate({ top: '60px' }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
        $("#accountbarid").animate({ height: '60px' }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
        $("#searchbarid").animate({ height: '0' }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
        $('#contentid').animate({ marginTop: '120px' }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
        $(this).addClass('open');  
  }
  });
  $("#searchid").on('click',function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('open')) {
        $("#topheaderid").animate({ top: '0' }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
            $("#accountbarid").animate({ height: '0' }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
        $("#searchbarid").animate({ height: '0' }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
        $('#contentid').animate({ marginTop: '60px' }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
         $(this).removeClass('open');   
  } else {
        $("#topheaderid").animate({ top: '0' }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
            $("#accountbarid").animate({ height: '0' }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
        $("#searchbarid").animate({ height: '60px' }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
        $('#contentid').animate({ marginTop: '120px' }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
        $(this).addClass('open');  
  }
  });
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When opening either of the toolbars, just ensure the "open" class of the other toolbar is removed. See code below.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $("#account").on('click',function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('open')) {
        $("#topheaderid").animate({ top: '0' }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
        $("#accountbarid").animate({ height: '0' }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
        $("#searchbarid").animate({ height: '0' }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
        $('#contentid').animate({ marginTop: '60px' }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
        $(this).removeClass('open');   
  } else {
        $("#topheaderid").animate({ top: '60px' }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
        $("#accountbarid").animate({ height: '60px' }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
        $("#searchbarid").animate({ height: '0' }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
        $('#contentid').animate({ marginTop: '120px' }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
        $(this).addClass('open');  
        $("#searchid").removeClass('open');
  }
  });
  $("#searchid").on('click',function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('open')) {
        $("#topheaderid").animate({ top: '0' }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
            $("#accountbarid").animate({ height: '0' }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
        $("#searchbarid").animate({ height: '0' }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
        $('#contentid').animate({ marginTop: '60px' }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
         $(this).removeClass('open');   
  } else {
        $("#topheaderid").animate({ top: '0' }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
            $("#accountbarid").animate({ height: '0' }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
        $("#searchbarid").animate({ height: '60px' }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
        $('#contentid').animate({ marginTop: '120px' }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
        $(this).addClass('open');
        $("#account").removeClass('open');
  }
  });
});
```